# React Native output is .class (for android) and .c (for iOS)

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, react-native

i read that React Native will create native apps (both android and ios) and not like IONIC or Sencha Touch which use cordova.

So will the output is .class for andorid and .c or .shift for iphone apps.
What i mean is when we build the React Native project for android it will convert the java script to a normal android project (with java classes, AndroidManifist.xml etc)

Can someone please clarify me on this.

Need to finalize whether to use Ionic or React Native for my next project because Sencha Touch is dead now.

Thanks
Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native *does not convert* JavaScript into Java or Objective C, it's a platform that simply lets you *use* JavaScript to make bridged native calls depending on the platform you are writing for. This allows you to share a lot of business logic while being able to build a platform-specific native-performant app.

The app's build output is still regular .class or .m or .swift, but it also includes your JavaScript.

Just read the home page's description: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I believe there is no need for Cordova.